# How to retain the active selection in a list after an operation in another html pane?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask

I am using flask (Jinja) framework. I have two html panes, each rendered using separate templates. The left pane has a list of items

```
a
b
c
d
```

On the right pane, there is a number of operations I can do with the items on the left `(a,b,c,d)`. For example, if the left pane list represents a the files in the current directory, on the right I can have operations such as modifying the file (including a submit button that commits the change). Every time I make some change to the files listed on the left pane and press the submit button, I will have to refresh the pane on the left. This refresh is a basic `.get()` operation, such as

```
$.get("/" + xxx + "/yyy?id=" $("#itemid"), function(res){
  $("#list").html(res); 
})
```

Assuming this get/refresh is working. My selection on the list (e.g. select "c") will be gone after the refresh. I want to retain the selection on item "c" on the list.

So, in `LEFTPANE.html`, the list is constructed like the following:

```
<div id="list">
  <ul>{% for item in list %}
    <li data-id="{{ item['id'] }}">
      {{ item['id'] }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In `RIGHTPANE.html`, it looks like the following inside the `submitBtn.click()`:
(this is what will be executed when submit button is clicked)

```
$.get("/" + xxx + "/yyy", function(res){
  $("#list").html(res);
  //This is what I need to do:
  $($("#list ul li").attr("data-id") == {{ itemid }}).addClass("active"); //active==selected==highlighted
})
```

Obviously I wouldn't post this question if I already know how to find that selection given the `itemid`. What's the appropriate syntax or method to make that selection highlighted (`active`)? Thanks so much!